# Twisted weak reference to non object python

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted, weak-references

I am currently building a scraper with scrapy which unfortunately fails and with the following error log. I tried running it with crawler runner and crawler process but both versions fail. I tried to figure out if i've used twisted incorrectly but i think i did it correctly.

```
2018-04-18 23:55:46 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/flo/PycharmProjects/Tensortest/Car_Analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
result = g.send(result)
File "/home/flo/PycharmProjects/Tensortest/Car_Analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 79, in crawl
self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/flo/PycharmProjects/Tensortest/Car_Analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 102, in _create_spider
return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/flo/PycharmProjects/Tensortest/Car_Analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 52, in from_crawler
spider._set_crawler(crawler)
File "/home/flo/PycharmProjects/Tensortest/Car_Analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 67, in _set_crawler
crawler.signals.connect(self.close, signals.spider_closed)
File "/home/flo/PycharmProjects/Tensortest/Car_Analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/signalmanager.py", line 26, in connect
return dispatcher.connect(receiver, signal, **kwargs)
File "/home/flo/PycharmProjects/Tensortest/Car_Analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydispatch/dispatcher.py", line 130, in connect
receiver = saferef.safeRef(receiver, onDelete=_removeReceiver)
File "/home/flo/PycharmProjects/Tensortest/Car_Analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydispatch/saferef.py", line 32, in safeRef
return weakref.ref(target, onDelete)
TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'NoneType' object
```

My Code looks like this

```
import scrapy
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from classes import cars

LINKS = []
CARS = []

class AutoSpiderLinks(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Auto_get_links"
    ROOT_URL = "https://www.somewebsite"
    global LINKS

def geturls(self):
    main_url = "https://www.somewebsite"
    target_url = []
    for x in range(1, 2):
        target_url.append(main_url + "&page=" + str(x))
        print(target_url.append(main_url + "&page=" + str(x)))
    return target_url

def start_requests(self):
    urls = AutoSpiderLinks.geturls(self)
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    important_divs = response.css('div.cldt-summary-titles').extract()
    AutoSpiderLinks.convert(self, important_divs)

def main():
   configure_logging()
   runner = CrawlerRunner()
   runner.crawl(AutoSpiderLinks)
   runner.crawl(DeepSpider)
   d = runner.join()
   d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

if __name__ == '__main__'
   main()
```

Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've figured it out. Apparently you can not configure the threading inside the main function. The fix for this issue was straight forward with reactor.

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def main():
    configure_logging()
    runner = CrawlerRunner()
    yield runner.crawl(AutoSpiderLinks)
    yield runner.crawl(DeepSpider)
    reactor.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    reactor.run()
```